# How do I have two methods in separate classes wait before continuing execution?

Tags: java, swing, java-8

I have two classes, `BlackJack` and `BlackJackPane`, `BlackJack` has a method called `dealCards()` which gives a class called `Player` a `Card` by looping from the first `Player` to the last `Player` twice like in a real game of blackjack where each player is dealt one card at a time.

The `BlackJackPane` is a JFrame that contains JButtons and JLabels. The JButton `deal` when clicked has a `.actionCommand("deal")` and an `ActionListener` with a Lambda expression that calls the instance variable `blackjack` in `BlackJackPane` to deal cards, `blackjack.dealCards()`. The `ActionListener` also determines what kind of card from a regular 52 card deck the `Player` was dealt to display the proper `Card` the `Player` has.

I would PREFER to have the `dealCards()` method in `BlackJack` wait after passing a `Card` to a `Player` for a JLabel to be created and displayed in the JFrame, however, I do not know how to make this work across classes. I am open to other creative options or tips on how to improve my code.

I am trying to keep the classes encapsulated and I/O confined in `BlackJackPane`.

This is my class `BlackJack`

```
public class BlackJack
{

   private final Deck deck;
   private final ArrayList<Player> player;
   private final int numOfPlayers;

   public BlackJack(int players)
   {
       this.numOfPlayers = players + 1; // +1 for dealer, dealer is always first in arrayList
       this.deck = new Deck(Deck.TYPE[0]);
       this.player = new ArrayList();
       for (int i = 0; i < players + 1; i++)
       {
           this.player.add(new Player((i == 0))); //i == 0 is to say true to Player constructor that it is the dealer or cpu
       }
   }

   public void DealCards()
   {
       deck.shuffle();

       for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < player.size(); j++)
           {
               player.get(j).getHand().add(deck.getCard(0));
               deck.remove(0);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This is the `BlackJackPane`

```
    public class BlackJackPane extends JFrame
    {

       private BlackJack blackjack;
       private JLabel pokerTable;
       private JButton hit, stay, split, deal, hiddenCard;

       public BlackJackPane(BlackJack blackjack) throws IOException
       {
          this.blackjack = blackjack;
          display();
       }

       private void display() throws IOException
       {


        deal.addActionListener((event) ->
        {
            if (event.getActionCommand().equals("deal"))
            {
                blackjack.DealCards();

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < blackjack.getNumOfPlayers(); j++)
                    {
                        if (blackjack.getPlayer(j).isCpu() && i != 1) //One card dealer has is face down
                        {

                        } else
                        {
                            if (blackjack.getPlayer(j).getHand().get(i).getFace() == 0) // face = 2
                            {
                                if (blackjack.getPlayer(j).getHand().get(i).getSuit() == 0) //clubs
                                {
                                   //Code to make and display the JLabel within the JFrame
                                } else if (blackjack.getPlayer(j).getHand().get(i).getSuit() == 1) //diamonds
                                {

                                } else if (blackjack.getPlayer(j).getHand().get(i).getSuit() == 2) //hearts
                                {

                                } else //spades
                                {

                                }
                            } else if() //and so on for 52 cards
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could redefine your `dealCards` method to take some callback to be invoked after each card is dealt.

```
public void dealCards(BiConsumer<Player, Card> onDealtCallback) {
    for (Player player : players) {
        Card dealt = this.getNextCardToDeal();
        onDealtCallback.accept(player, dealt);
    }
}
```

And then invoke it with something like:

```
public void callIt() {
    this.blackJack.dealCards(this::drawLabel);
}

public void drawLabel(Player player, Card card) {
    // TODO
}
```

I can't say this is the most object-oriented approach, and it doesn't give a nice separation of state and UI.  But it should do what you're trying to do.

(Note: this isn't the place for code review, so I'm resisting the urge to offer further suggestions on 'how to improve your code'.)

Comment: I'll try and implement this tonight and get back to you